# Autogenerated web.config not accepted by IIS 10

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-config

I want to publish a entity framework core (.Net) to a IIS. 
For this I publish the application in Visual Studio Community 2017. When I publish the application the web.config file will be auto generated as the following

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\basket.api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: ba174064-1719-4e47-a0c3-5e8cff312047-->
```

I go to my IIS 10 
[image: IIS 10]
I post it into the default website. Into to the location "C:\inetpub\wwwroot".
I start the web site an access via the webbrowser localhost.

I get allways the following error message:
[image: Error page]

I check the web page of Microsoft of the error code 0x8007000d,it is basicly saying that the format of a XML Element is not correct. Which is impossible I check all the formating and also I let autogenerate by the Visual Studio when i publish the site. I tried everything and don't know what to do. I am very newbie in IIS stuff.

Comment: Could you please open the folder which you publishde the .net core web application and find out the web.config file and post the web.config file details information in your thread?

Comment: I added the web.config file above, or do I missunderstand your question? The web.config is the XML content above is the original file.

Comment: If you run a report the reason should be crystal clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html The most likely is that you forgot to install the so called server bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I will check it out